# SyncFusion Menu item doesn't disappear on mouse leave

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion: menuItemAdv control for showing a hierarchical menu items for an applications.
 OnMouseOver or OnMouseClicked(ExpandMode Property)it shows the sub items on mouse hover a menu items. But It doesn't disappear that list on mouse leave. However, If I click anywhere else on the windows(lost focus probably),then it cleans the sub menu item.

So, Instead of clearing the sub menu items on lost focus. I want to do that on mouse leave as user might open any other application without causing lost focus event and might get confused. So, I want to clear the item list on mouse leave.

I know, I can write a behavior and can hook it's on mouse leave event but I don't know how to clean that list. As there is no method exposed from this library. tempering with item source might screw something.

Any help is appreciated.

xaml is as following

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM></local:MainWindowVM>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

        <syncfusion:MenuAdv Width="300" Height="40" ItemsSource="{Binding League}" ExpandMode="ExpandOnMouseOver">
            <syncfusion:MenuAdv.ItemTemplate >
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:MenuList" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </syncfusion:MenuAdv.ItemTemplate>
        </syncfusion:MenuAdv>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Is code-behind allowed in your app?

Comment: I can manage to have later I can push it into behaviour

Answer (score 2):

We have checked the reported behavior and considered this as bug. The fix for this bug will be included in our volume 3 SP2 release which is scheduled to be rolled out by end of September.

Regards,
Durga S.